# IIS in .Net core looking for directory instead of controller

Tags: iis, .net-core, frameworks

Just switched from Framework to Core. Everything was working fine in framework

We have an application in IIS called GO nested under our main website.
MyWebsite/Go

the main page loads fine. Mywebsite.com/GO ==> calls /home/index
However if we go to a different action (MyWebsite.com/Go/buy) should call /buy/index
we get "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Obviously it's not a permission problem as the main page loads fine, it is just that IIS tries to look for the directory /Go/buy instead of the controller. (/Buy/Index) under the application /GO
Any ideas how to solved it?

Comment: In IIS, it is not allowed to set a core application as sub-application under another core or framework application. The sub-application will not work.

Comment: The sub application works. But just the default page of the sub application. so it is allowed. I need all the controllers to work

Comment: please read this url to understand that it is possible https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/advanced?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Yes,you're right. So I create two applications as Mainsite and subsite. Sub site can be accessed. I also created a common site and added subsite. It also worked. There is no  permission issue. I think you can set GO as main site to check whether it can be accessed, and create a new empty core application with multiple controllers and actions, deployed as sub site. Check whether it can be accessed. Another thing is checking authentication module of GO, enable anonymous authentication and windows authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, as I mentioned before, the Sub-app works but just the default page of the sub app (/Home/Index)
When i create a different route [Route("/Home/{product}")] Under BuyController it doesn't works as it tries to search for this file, instead of the controller. 

Doesn't work:
MySite.com/Go/Buy/Product1

Works:
MySite.com/Go

My IIS permissions are fine as the sub-App default works, i created a user with the privillages of accessing the whole site directory, assined it to the unmanaged pool (. net core) and also in IIS authenitcation.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you show the code of controller and action(don't need to post the detailed code of action, post like "public IActionResult Index(){...}")  and web.config? Please tell me the version of asp.net core so that I can reproduce this issue.

Comment: Version 3.1 .NET Core

  [Route("/Buy/{product}")]  

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
      }

And this controller is installed as a sub- application so to access it you access:
MyWEb.com/GO/Buy/Product1
Go is the sub application.
All works when debugging it on local host and accessing it with IIS express /buy/product.
Once installe on IIS under the application GO it looks for the file /buy/product instead of  the controller.
*The sub application works only if you access the HomeController i.e /Go/Index....

Comment: Your description confuses me. What do you mean "this controller is installed as a sub- application "? What I understand is GO is the name of application and alias when add it as sub application. I also cannot understand that how could /GO/index work. I created GO application and add Buycontroller.  In IIS Express, I can access localhost/buy/product1, localhost/home/index, but cannot access localhost/index. In IIS, I can access localhost/GO,localhost/GO/Buy/product1,localhost/GO/Home/index, but cannot access localhost/GO/Index.